# Project compiles with Ant. But if I open eclipse, the project no longer compiles

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, plovr

I'm on Windows.

I downloaded the source to a java project (Plovr) and I can build it with ant using cygwin.

But just opening it in Eclipse means it will never build again. If I open it in Eclipse and then close it again, it will no longer build. I also can't add files that were written in Eclipse.

---

Output:

```
javacc:

compile:
    [javac] Compiling 7 source files to C:\Users\Bryana\plovr\pulled\plovr-master\build\classes
    [javac] C:\Users\Bryana\plovr\pulled\plovr-master\closure\closure-stylesheets\build\genfiles\java\com\google\common\css\compiler\ast\GssParserCC.java:345: error: cannot access Type
    [javac]     public CssBooleanExpressionNode buildBoolExpressionNode(CssBooleanExpressionNode.Type type,
    [javac]                                                                                     ^
    [javac]   bad class file: C:\Users\Bryana\plovr\pulled\plovr-master\build\classes\com\google\common\css\compiler\ast\CssBooleanExpressionNode$Type.class
    [javac]     bad signature: ▒3i
    [javac]     Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.

BUILD FAILED
```

Using: jdk1.7.0_40 , Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 , Eclipse Juno Service Release 2

Comment: What versions of Java are Eclipse and Ant using?

Comment: @chrylis Added this info to the question

Comment: Please confirm from the command line and the Installed JREs window that they're using the same version.

Comment: Same version. Also, the difference is not between cygwin&ant vs Eclipse. It's between cygwin&ant before opening the project in Eclipse vs after opening it.

Comment: Looks like Eclipse is using a different version of the JDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this: http://suneelgv.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/java-lang-classformaterror-invalid-constant-pool-index-63-bad-class-file/ referring to that http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cayenne-user/200804.mbox/%3C0JZC008038T159@mail.uni-rostock.de%3E.

In your case the filterset or similar on-the-fly modification during copying - accidentally including class files - might not do any harm with Unix but convert line endings on Windows.

Comment: Sounds likely. It's not `filterset`. I'll have to comb through for something similar.